# Laravel with Livewire - using flatpickr for Date Range

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire, flatpickr

I have problems getting run `flatpickr` with Laravel and using it inside Livewire component.

Steps that I've done:

1. Installing `flatpickr`:

   `npm install flatpickr`
2. Inside `/resources/js/app.js` I've put:

   ```php
     import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
     window.flatpickr = flatpickr;
   ```
3. Inside layout file I've put `scripts` to the CDN:

   ```html
     <html>
     <!-- ... -->
     </footer>

        @livewireScripts
        @powerGridScripts
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.6.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
        @stack('js')
    </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Created in `/public/js/flatpickr.js` file for handling actions:

   ```js
     flatpickr("#test", {
        mode: "range"
     });
   ```
5. Put inside `notifications-management.blade.php` view the script path:

   ```html
    @if($modalNotificationCreateVisible)
        @livewire('create-notification-form')
    @endif
    @push('js')
       <script src="{{ asset('js/flatpickr.js') }}"> 
    </script>
    @endpush
   ```
6. Inside `create-notification-form`(it's a modal) I've put `<div>` which should be working as datepicker:

   ```html
     <div>
        <input id="test" type="text">
     </div>
   ```

The effect is not present. If I click on this `input` in the form is still working as the `text` one. Do someone have an idea how to handle it or maybe I've missed some steps?